# What is the meaning of ```alert(`${info} : ${pokemondetails[info]}\n`)```?

Tags: javascript, json

What is the meaning of `` alert(`${info} : ${pokemondetails[info]}\n`) `` in the following code? Can someone explain it to me in a simpler form?

```
let checkname = function(findname,findpokemongame)
{
   for(let thispokemon in findpokemongame.pokemon)
   {
      if(findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon].name == findname)
      {
         let pokemondetails = findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon];
         for(info in pokemondetails)
         {
            alert (`${info} : ${pokemondetails[info]}\n`); //explain this part in simple form
         }
      }
   }
}
checkname(findname, findpokemongame)
```

Comment: Take a look on [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

The code is using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them

Template literals are used to interpolate expressions(something which `return` a value) inside string without having crazy synatx using too much `+` signs.The line is same as

```
alert(info + " : " + pokemondetails[info] + "\n")
```